# How to loop vectors through a function that takes only two values at a time in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

```
lat <- c(45.08323,40.08323)
long <- c(-82.46797,-81.46797)
df <- data.frame(lat, long)

library(geonames) #To calibrate altitude
readLines(url("http://api.geonames.org/",open="r"))
options(geonamesUsername= "MyUsername") #Note you have to create a username one the 
website AND enable webservices on your geonames user account at 
https://www.geonames.org/manageaccount. 

GNsrtm3(54.481084,-3.220625)

   srtm3       lng      lat
1   797 -3.220625 54.48108
```

The `GNsrtm3` can take in only two values at a time, but I want to run a vector of lats and longs through the function. I wish to store all three values strm3, lng and lat in a data.frame `df.results`. I'm terrible at loops, but I attempted

```
  for(i in 1:length(df)){
  df.result <- GNsrtm3(df$lat[i],df$long[i])
  i = i + 1 }

  df$alt <- df.result$srtm3
```

I only get the first line of the answer. So its not taking in the vector. Any insights?

Comment: Instead of ‘length’ use ‘nrow’. Length of dataframes is number of columns, since it is a list. And do NOT increment the loop counter. It happens automatically as part of the ‘for’-function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently overwriting the value in `df.result` in each iteration. Also `for` loop does not need `i = i+ 1`, it auto increments the `i` value.

Initialise a list to store the values from each call and bind them together at the end of the loop to get one combined dataframe.

```
df.result <- vector('list', nrow(df))

for(i in seq(nrow(df))){
  df.result[[i]] <- GNsrtm3(df$lat[i],df$long[i])
}

df.result <- do.call(rbind, df.result)
```

---

Some other alternatives which does not involve explicit `for` loops would be -

```
df.result <- do.call(rbind, Map(GNsrtm3, df$lat, df$long))
df.result <- purrr::map2_df(df$lat, df$long, GNsrtm3)
```